# bottom border of last item missing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've a page with following HTML and uses JQuery Mobile UI framework. I've 2 queries:

1) Why bottom-border of last element hides? If I remove header, it starts appearing. Please suggest how can I keep header such that bottom-border doesn't hides.

2) Why does loader keeps visible even after page has loaded - Solved.. I was missing closing header

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>app</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header data-role="header">

            <h1>
                My Application</h1>
        </header>


        <article data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" >
                <li><a href="#">
                        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
                        <img src="http://www.f-secure.com/static/img/labs_global/Icons/98/forum_bubbles_icon.png" alt="cards"/>
                        <p>Select this option to lorum ipsum</p></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
                        <img src="http://www.f-secure.com/static/img/labs_global/Icons/98/forum_bubbles_icon.png" alt="cards"/>
                        <p>Select this option to lorum ipsum</p></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                        <h1>Heading 3</h1>
                        <img src="http://www.f-secure.com/static/img/labs_global/Icons/98/forum_bubbles_icon.png" alt="cards"/>
                        <p>Select this option to lorum ipsum</p></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                        <h1>Heading 4</h1>                
                        <img src="http://www.f-secure.com/static/img/labs_global/Icons/98/forum_bubbles_icon.png" alt="cards"/>
                        <p>Select this option to lorum ipsum</p></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </article>


    </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Additional Comment - If I remove header OR reduce number of elements to say 2, then bottom border appears properly. But with 4 elements and a header, it hides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the body tag.. Close your head before opening body...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       [...]
    </body>
</html>
```

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bjzpA/).

Comment: Hi Thanks.. .That was a typo from my side. It fixes the loader issue. Thanks for pointing that. However, my main query is still open :( Why doesn't the bottom border appears under  last element of list view.

Comment: I don't see the root of the problem, but adding &nbsp; after ul helps. Check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjzpA/1/).

Comment: Thanks.. adding &nbsp; solved the issue. However, curious what was the problem and how this space fixed it. Anyone??